# I'm getting a 404 when issuing an ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

Here is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
      url: "/api/clients/UpdateResourceContactProductsByResourceContactId/" + id,
     type: 'POST',
     data: { strIds: strIds },
  success: function (data) {
   }
});
```

where id is the integer and strIds is a string contantenation of integers, they look like **123_254_741_6650** ...

And this the server side code ...

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateResourceContactProductsByResourceContactId
       (int id, string strIds)
{
   //...
}
```

When I hit the update button, I'm getting the following error:

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 
 'http://localhost/api/clients/UpdateResourceContactProductsByResourceContactId/22757'.",
 "MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Clients' that matches the request."}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried url: "/api/clients/UpdateResourceContactProductsByResourceContactId?id=" + id + "&strIds=" + strIds,

Comment: As @artm said - can you navigate directly to `http://localhost/api/clients/UpdateResourceContactProductsByResourceContactId/22757`? If you're really getting a `404`, the ajax itself isn't to blame.

Comment: Well I can tell you that it isn't a string being passed to your controller that's for sure, because you're sending it as part of the `POST`. The Router is not parsing `strIds` as an argument of the URL because it is being passed in the `HTTP BODY` not the `URL`. Just like @artm said, move the `strIds` declaration into the URL concatentation.

Comment: @admdrew: Now it's hitting the action. However, it looks like I'm exposing all my data. I thought that's a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: "/api/clients/UpdateResourceContactProductsByResourceContactId",
    type: 'POST',
    data: { id: id, strIds: strIds },
    success: function (data) {
   }
 });
```

Comment: I'm getting again 404.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're passing the data wrong.  You are passing a object.  Either change you method to accept a JObject and use dynamic to pull the `strIds` out, pass the string by itself, or use it as a URL parameter.

```
//example using JObject below
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateResourceContactProductsByResourceContactId(int id, JObject data)//JObject requires Json.NET
{
   dynamic json = data;
   string ids = json.strIds
}
```

If you are going to POST an object you need to call JSON.stringify on it too in the javascript.

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ strIds: strIds });
$.ajax({
    async: false,
      url: "/api/clients/UpdateResourceContactProductsByResourceContactId/" + id,
     type: 'POST',
     data: data,
  success: function (data) {
   }
});
```